# SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') value in Windows Server 2008 + SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

Having an environment Windows Server 2008 + SQL Server 2012.

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')
```

Will the below query return 11.X.XXXX.XX or 10.XX.XXXX.X

Please share whether SERVERPROPERTY function checks the SQL Server version or Windows Server version.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the official documentation for [SERVERPROPERTY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/serverproperty-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> ProductVersion    Version of the instance of SQL Server, in the form of 'major.minor.build.revision'.

So `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')` will give you the database engine version. To get information about the OS, use [sys.dm_os_windows_info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-windows-info-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
select * from sys.dm_os_windows_info
```

Comment: Appreciate Andrey!!

Comment: @VENKATESH In SO you can express your appreciation by accepting and upvoting helpful answers :) [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)